# python jdon to csv ，Works with all types of codes，

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, nested

I often need to convert JSON files to csv files. There are many types of JSON files, regular or nested, so is there any code that can convert all types to csv files?
I often need to convert JSON files to csv files. There are many types of JSON files, regular or nested, so is there any code that can convert all types to csv files?

Here's my code, but it can only convert small files, and for files in the tens or tens of GBs, it can get a "memory error". Is there a more efficient code, or modify my code to read line by line or in chunks to reduce memory usage.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

file_path = "F:\\1.json"
with open(file_path, 'r',encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    file_data = fh.readlines()

all_data = []
for data in file_data:
    data = data.strip()
    if data:
        all_data.append(json.loads(data))
df = pd.json_normalize(all_data)

df.to_csv('F:\\1.csv',encoding='utf-8',index=False)
```

JSON file

```
{"_index":"core-bvd-dmc","_type":"_doc","_id":"e22762d5c4b81fbcad62b5c1d77226ec","_score":1,"_source":{"a_id":"P305906272","a_id_type":"Contact ID","a_name":"Mr Chuanzong Chen","a_name_normal":"MR CHUANZONG CHEN","a_job_title":"Executive director and general manager","relationship":"Currently works for (Executive director and general manager)","b_id":"CN9390051924","b_id_type":"BVD ID","b_name":"Yantai haofeng trade co., ltd.","b_name_normal":"YANTAI HAOFENG TRADE CO","b_country_code":"CN","b_country":"China","b_in_compliance_db":false,"b_nationality":"CN","b_street_address":"Bei da jie 53hao 1609shi; Zhi fu qu","b_city":"Yantai","b_postcode":"264000","b_region":"East China|Shandong","b_phone":"+86 18354522200","b_email":"18354522200@163.com","b_latitude":37.511873,"b_longitude":121.396883,"b_geo_accuracy":"Community","b_national_ids":{"Unified social credit code":["91370602073035263P"],"Trade register number":["370602200112047"],"NOC":["073035263"]},"dates":{"date_of_birth":null},"file_name":"/media/hedwig/iforce/data/BvD/s3-transfer/SuperTable_v3_json/dmc/part-00020-7b09c546-2adc-413e-9e68-18b300e205cf-c000.json","b_geo_point":{"lat":37.511873,"lon":121.396883}}}
{"_index":"core-bvd-dmc","_type":"_doc","_id":"97871f8842398794e380a748f5b82ea5","_score":1,"_source":{"a_id":"P305888975","a_id_type":"Contact ID","a_name":"Mr Hengchao Jiang","a_name_normal":"MR HENGCHAO JIANG","a_job_title":"Legal representative","relationship":"Currently works for (Legal representative)","b_id":"CN9390053357","b_id_type":"BVD ID","b_name":"Yantai ji hong educate request information co., ltd.","b_name_normal":"YANTAI JI HONG EDUCATE REQUEST INFORMATION CO","b_country_code":"CN","b_country":"China","b_in_compliance_db":false,"b_nationality":"CN","b_street_address":"Ying chun da jie 131hao nei 1hao; Lai shan qu","b_city":"Yantai","b_postcode":"264000","b_region":"East China|Shandong","b_phone":"+86 18694982900","b_email":"xyw_700@163.com","b_latitude":37.511873,"b_longitude":121.396883,"b_geo_accuracy":"Community","b_national_ids":{"NOC":["597807789"],"Trade register number":["370613200023836"],"Unified social credit code":["913706135978077898"]},"dates":{"date_of_birth":null},"file_name":"/media/hedwig/iforce/data/BvD/s3-transfer/SuperTable_v3_json/dmc/part-00020-7b09c546-2adc-413e-9e68-18b300e205cf-c000.json","b_geo_point":{"lat":37.511873,"lon":121.396883}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no generic way to convert an arbitrarily nested JSON file to CSV – at least not into a CSV that would make sense or be generically usable.